# PHP curl_multi - simple GET calls return "No Input File Specifed" on ~10% of urls

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I have an internal script `get_url.php` which performs a cURL call to a specified url, depending on the specified GET params.

I am running an additional script `get_multi_urls.php` which uses `curl_multi` to call `get_url.php` for 25 different urls.

After printing the results pulled from `get_multi_urls.php`, I notice that some results return `No input file specified.`. There is no pattern to which `get_url.php` get params return this result. Sometimes it could be `?source=A`, or `?source=B`, or `...etc`.

When I call the same url which returns `no input file specified` on it's own, it prints the actual contents of the curl response.

Does anyone have any insight into why I am receiving this result? Is there a limit to the number of handles `curl_mutli` can execute?